Why can I not include metal_float64 library in Xcode
I want to use the library https://github.com/philipturner/metal-float64, and successfully built and ran tests, next copied the built MetalFloat64 folder into Xcode, but I do not know how to properly include it, the docs say to use #include <metal_float64> however the file cannot be found, any help would be appreciated
tried pointing it at the file
#include "MetalFloat64/usr/include/metal_float64"

but that resulted in there being several errors I cannot find, making me think Im doing something wrong, the errors are:

there is also no atomic.h file I can find.
Build phase settings:

Build Settings search paths:


Did you tried : « @import metal_float64 » . To import the module and its interface in Objective-C code ?
